# Regex for MS Word for detecting subtitle

Tags: replace, ms-word, wildcard

I have a MS Word Documents with its subtitle all in font-size 18px and bold. I want to find them all and replace them with something else. There I use Ctrl+H, enabling wldcards, chossing the font style (fontsize and bold), and use the regex `(*{1,})`. However, this regex would find occurrences for every single character. How can I make every whole subtitle as a single occurence? Thanks

Comment: You don't need regex for this - not even Word's *wildcards* - for what you've described all you need is a Find/Replace that works with the font attributes.

Comment: @macropod but I still want to keep the subtitle. I just want to wrap it with something else.  ie (some text)\1(some text). thx.

Comment: As commented to your duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58572448/how-can-i-wrap-my-subtitles-in-ms-word-with-some-predefined-tags this is an ***end-user** issue and ***off-topic*** on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CindyMeister yes, and why is it not closed?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Word *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = ([!^13]@)^13
Replace = Before Text \1 After text^p
```

and you specify the font attributes as part of the Find parameters. No code required, though you could use a macro if you really want to - the macro recorder will replicate the F/R parameters.